# configure prerender.io with nginx and ssl

Tags: angularjs, node.js, linux, nginx, prerender

Hi i have the below nginx configuration in (site-enabled) folder and i want to add some prerender.io configurations for my angularjs app, but it's seems to not work.

I supose that in here we need to configure the prender to wokr well with the ssl.

```
   server {
    listen 443;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name www.test.com test.com;
server_tokens off;
if ($host = 'test.com') {
   return 301 https://www.test.com$request_uri;
}

root /home/test/public;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:30m;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA';

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;



location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; 
            includeSubDomains" always;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          server_tokens off;
 }


 }

    server {
   listen  80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name    www.test.com test.com;
   return         301 https://www.test.com$request_uri;
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked at prerender's nginx configuration? https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802

Comment: Hi  mcranston18 thanks for your reply but actually i tried but without success !! for that reason i'm asking

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? You need to explain the error

Comment: I sent the code i test as response, if you want to check it !!

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is the configuration i did. When i test using nginx -t, there is no error but ther server dosen't run.

```
   server {
    listen 443;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name www.test.com test.com;
server_tokens off;
if ($host = 'test.com') {
   return 301 https://www.test.com$request_uri;
}

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:30m;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA';

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

root /home/test/test/public;
index  index.html.gz;


location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
}

location /prerender {
#proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token wGvPrLPdSuDSpoxyOa46;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
server_tokens off;


location @prerender {
#proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token key;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" 
  always;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
server_tokens off;

 set $prerender 0;
if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
    set $prerender 1;
}
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
    set $prerender 1;
}
if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
    set $prerender 0;
}
if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
    set $prerender 0;
}

#resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
resolver 8.8.8.8;

 if ($prerender = 1) {

    #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx 
    caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
    set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
    rewrite .* /https://$host$request_uri? break;
    proxy_pass http://$prerender;
}
if ($prerender = 0) {
    rewrite .* /index.html break;
}
  }

}

 server {
   listen  80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name    www.test.com test.com;
   return  301 https://www.test.com$request_uri;
}
```